# Separate the different multiple elements in an image (overlapping objects)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

My problem is as follows:
I have an image that contains two overlapping objects, and I'm trying to separate them in order to draw the outline of each object(edges). Here's my Python code along with the results.

I attempted to solve the issue of separating overlapping objects in an image using Python.The image I worked with contained two objects that were overlapping each other. My objective was to extract and separate the two objects to obtain their individual outlines. I implemented a Python code snippet to tackle this problem. My goal was to obtain separate masks or regions corresponding to each object.
Here is a link to download the image

[image: the picture]

[google drive link to the picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kXv0hzUKv3P0D_LlXNxZoSs_ZM5SP1NI/view?usp=sharing)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_path = '/content/423628443_0.jpg'

image = cv2.imread(image_path, 0)

_, binary_image = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(binary_image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)


closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)

edges = cv2.Canny(closing, 30, 150)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

image_with_contours = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.drawContours(image_with_contours, contours, -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))

plt.subplot(1, 5, 1)
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Original Image')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(1, 5, 2)
plt.imshow(binary_image, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Binary Image')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(1, 5, 3)
plt.imshow(opening, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Opening')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(1, 5, 4)
plt.imshow(closing, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Closing')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(1, 5, 5)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image_with_contours, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('Edges')
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Results of this python script:

[image: 2]